# Mysql Decimal Number Issue

Tags: mysql, decimal

I am trying to save numbers with up to three decimal points in MySQL database. I tried float, float(3,2) and decimal(3,2) but none of them saves them correctly. Please suggest which datatype should I use.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of *how* you are trying to "save" those values (maybe the issue is not storage but in the command)? Plus some examples of values you tried and the result

Comment: `decimal(3,2)` means "3 digits total, and 2 of them decimal".

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html):

```
salary DECIMAL(5,2)
```

> In this example, 5 is the precision and 2 is the scale. The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

So for 3 decimals, you would need a "3" as second value. Also check the first digit: will all your expected numbers fit in that amount of digits?

The salary column above will store values up to 999.99. For a value of 1000 or higher (or -1000 and lower), you will get an error. More decimals (12.345) lead to a warning that the value is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use `FLOAT(m,n)`.

`DECIMAL(3,2)` has a max of 9.99
`DECIMAL(5,3)` has a max of 99.999
`DECIMAL(8,3)` has a max of 99999.999

The second and third examples have "three decimal *places*" (only 1 "decimal point")

IP addresses (eg, 192.168.11.22) have 3 "decimal points".

If "none of them saves them correctly", then please provide an example `INSERT` or `UPDATE` that is not working correctly, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.