Does inserting a string into `DECIMAL` column lose precision in MySQL?
I've read 13.1.3 Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value) - DECIMAL, NUMERIC, but nothing about the topic is mentioned.
As far as I tested, I can INSERT a string literal such as '123.45' into a DECIMAL(5, 2) column, but does this insertion lose precision?
Similarly, does SELECTing a DECIMAL column as a string in any programming language lose accuracy?
Finally, this is what I want to ask the most: in which section of the official documentation are they explained? I want a strict understanding about the topic.

It seems many people misunderstand the OP. What I want to ask is NOT something like "what is DECIMAL type" or "how to use DECIMAL" but "how does the insertion of string into DECIMAL affect its accuracy".
In other words, as clarified in this comment,

As written in the OP, I've already read the documentation. DECIMAL(5, 2) should represent 123.45 with exact precision but the point of the OP is the use of string. Inserting a string into a numeric column invokes some conversion under the hood, and I want to know how it works. For example, it is unlikely but possible that the string is first interpreted as an IEEE 754 floating-point value and then the parser truncates the result to store it into DECIMAL column. Without documentation, we cannot conclude anything and the documentation is what I want as clearly stated in the OP.


If the amount of digits in the string literal does not exceed the amount of digits in the datatype then the precision is not lost. Otherwise the value is obviously rounded (when integer part does not exceed and non-strict mode is set, a warning is generated) or an error is generated.

Have you considered consulting the documentation? What exactly do you think DECIMAL(5,2) means?

@Akina Do you know in which section of the official documentation are they explained? I want a strict understanding.

@user207421 As written in the OP, I've already read the documentation. DECIMAL(5, 2) should represent 123.45 with exact precision but the point of the OP is the use of string. Inserting a string into a numeric column invokes some conversion under the hood, and I want to know how it works. For example, it is unlikely but possible that the string is first interpreted as an IEEE 754 floating-point value and then the parser truncates the result to store it into DECIMAL column. Without documentation, we cannot conclude anything and the documentation is what I want as clearly stated in the OP.

Do you know in which section of the official documentation are they explained? Maybe you may find this in Internals... if not then you'd investigate server's source codes.

Similar type of issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560079/mysql-decimal-number-issue

@ynn That would defeat the whole point of the type.

MySQL DECIMAL(m,n) function data type is an exact numeric data type defined by its precision (total number of digits, m) and scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point, n).
Now, a decimal number define as:

First get the maximum possible numeric digits or whole number digits (x) of your data column and then find the round off digits (y).
So, m & n should be define as:
     m → (x+y) ≡ total number of digits of whole_number & decimal_number
and 
     n → y ≡ total number of decimal digits

and relation between m & n is:
   m >= n and m >= 1
   (m-n) = maximum number of digits left side of the decimal point (max whole number digits)

This is official documentation where explained it in details
DECIMAL Data Type Characteristics
I hope this will resolve your doubts

Thank you for your answer but it seems there is the same misunderstanding as this comment. Please see this comment.

I think this will help your string to decimal type conversion issue and precision loss issue. link - https://github.com/twitter-forks/mysql/blob/master/strings/decimal.c, check function internal_str2dec(). @ynn
